# Sending data from Fraggment_A in Activity 1 to Fragment_B in Activity 2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a **Fragment_A** on **Activity_1** and whenever a Button is clicked in the **Fragment_A** I have to start ***Activity_2*** witch have a **Fragment_B**

So i need to send a **user_Id** from the **Fragment_A** in **Activity 1** to the **Fragment_B**  in **activity_2**.
Is there any way to send the data directly from **Frament_A** in **Activity_1** to **Fragment_B** in **Activity_2**?

I am a student , so i am a beginner and i did found this question here but i didn't understand what to do to solve this
I did find some solution about interface but i didn't know how to do it

i keep getting  class_id null

**Language : Kotlin**

**Class : ClassesAdapter**

```
class ClassesAdapter(val c:Fragment,val l:android.content.Context? ,val classeslist: ArrayList<Classes>) : RecyclerView.Adapter <ClassesAdapter.ClassesViewHolder> (){
    lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var DataBase : DatabaseReference
    lateinit var DataBase2 : DatabaseReference
    lateinit var clipboardManager: ClipboardManager


    private lateinit var mListener :onItemClickListener

    interface onItemClickListener {

        fun onItemClick(position :Int)

    }

    /*fun setOnItemClickListener(listener : onItemClickListener){

       // mListener=listener

    }*/

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ClassesViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.class_items2,parent,false)
        //return ClassesViewHolder(itemView,mListener)
        return ClassesViewHolder(itemView,)
    }


  
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ClassesViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val currentitem = classeslist[position]
            holder.classname.text = currentitem.name
            holder.classrole.text = currentitem.role
    
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    
    
                val intent = Intent(l, DetailedClassActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("classId", currentitem.class_id)
                l!!.startActivity(intent)
    
            }
```

**Class : Acttivity2 who has the fragment iwant to send it the class_id**`

```
 package com.example.myclass1
    
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    import com.example.myclass1.databinding.ActivityDetailedClassBinding
    import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
    
class DetailedClassActivity : DrawerBaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailedClassBinding
    //lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
    override lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityDetailedClassBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // add it to change the toolbar title's to the activity name
        val actionBar = supportActionBar
        if (actionBar != null) {
            val dynamicTitle: String = HomeActivity::class.java.simpleName
            //Setting a dynamic title at runtime. Here, it displays the current activity name
            actionBar.setTitle("Home")
        }


        // navigate between documents ,notification and chatroom  :  tabLayout
        val tablayout2 : TabLayout =findViewById(R.id.tab_layout2)
        val viewpager21 : ViewPager2 =findViewById(R.id.viewPager21)
        val adapter =PagerAdapter2(supportFragmentManager,lifecycle)
        viewpager21.adapter = adapter
        TabLayoutMediator(tablayout2, viewpager21) { tab, position ->
            when(position){
                0->{tab.text="Documents"}
                1->{tab.text="Note"}
                2->{tab.text="ChatRoom"}
            }
        }.attach()


       

    val intent=getIntent()
    var classId= intent.getStringExtra("classId")
      

fun getMyData(): String? {
    return classId
    }

    }
```

class : fragment B

```
   enter code here
     btnAddcourse.setOnClickListener {
                var nameofthecourse = Coursename.text.toString().trim()
                var course_id :String?=DataBase3.push().key
                
                var classId = arguments?.getString("classId")
               
                
                val dateofthecourse: String = formatTimeStamp()
    
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nameofthecourse)) {
                    // No name added
                    Coursename.error = "No name added !! Please enter the name of the class"
                }
                else{
                    courseList.add(Course(course_id,nameofthecourse,dateofthecourse,classId))
                    coursesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Adding Course Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //Toast.makeText(activity,"class_id is null ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    if (classId != null) {
                        addCourseToDataBase(course_id!!,nameofthecourse,dateofthecourse,classId)
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(activity,"class_id is null ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: why are you making 1 fragment for each activity you can make multiple fragments for a single activity

Comment: yes i did 
i have 2 fragments in activity_1 and 3 fragments  in activity 2
i need only to send the " group_id " from the fragment 1 in activity  1 to   fragment 2 in activity  2

Comment: did you solve the problem completely

Comment: no same thing 
class_id =null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fragmentA

```
button.setOnClickListener { 
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), Activity2::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("user_Id", user_Id)
                startActivity(intent)
 }
```

activity2

```
val intent = getIntent()
val message = intent.getStringExtra("user_Id")

val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("user_Id", message) //the part i updated
val fragmet= fragment_B()   
fragmet.setArguments(bundle)
```

fragmentB

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_B, container, false)
    val bundle = this.arguments //the part i updated
    val myString = bundle!!.getString("user_Id", "defaultValue") //the part i updated
}
```

Comment: I hope I explained, this code will work. tried

Comment: thanks for annserwing i tried it and this line  :

val strtext = arguments!!.getString("user_Id")

 he tell me to use requireArguments() insted of argumets!!

and even when i do change it the app crush 

:Fragment DocumentsFragment{6e7e184} (0b6bba14-64f3-47cf-ac99-c812758d9c3e tag=f0) does not have any arguments.

Comment: I updated my code again, can you check it again?

Comment: i checked same thing 
but it worked when i change it like this :
var myString = arguments?.getString("classId")
but the id i get is null 
i put tost to check it and its null

Comment: you will soon succeed :D

Comment: I think you can give at least 1 vote to support

Comment: Can you share your code, maybe we're missing something

Comment: yeah sorry brother
im gonna try to share it
thank you so much

Comment: I'm waiting for you, no sleep until you solve this code :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244244/discussion-between-mouhamed-mokhtar-oubaya-and-omer-seyfettin-yavuzyigit).

Comment: come to the discussion chat

Comment: Sorry I'm in school i will come later

Comment: Are you available

Comment: we will solve the problem in a different way

Comment: yes im here  
how is that ?

Comment: can you wait for me 5 minutes

Comment: go to the chat room

Comment: i dont know wwhat happend to the chatroom are you there ?

Comment: I'm there, I'm writing, don't you receive a message?

Comment: no 
can we use other chatroom ?

Comment: ok where is the other chat room

Answer (score 1):

1-Read About Singleton Design Pattern
for make user id global in all app

1. [read it to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164144/right-way-way-to-implement-singleton-in-android-for-data-sharing-between-activit)

2-Shared Preference :save user id to can using for all app

1. [Shared Preferences](https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial)

3-you can try Navigation Args : better choose for performance
and can use it for movement through you app

1. [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data)